# How to post dictionary values from Postman to a .net core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I'm creating a simple Web API using .Net core 3.1 and I am having issues successfully posting a dictionary using Postman.

I have the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/metas")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Meta), 201)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMeta([FromForm] NewMeta newMeta)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The NewMeta currently looks like this:

```
public class NewMeta
{

    /// <summary>
    /// File descriptors
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, object> Refs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Associated file
    /// </summary>
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

}
```

I am trying to use Postman to POST dictionary data as well as a file.

I've tried using the various Key/Value settings within postman. An example shown in the images.

[image]

Results in :

[image]

How can i pass in a value? This API is early in its development so I can change anything that is needed.

Comment: Your dictionary is of type `string, object` but your passsing in `string, int`

Comment: I don't think you can use plain `object` for Web API Calls. Try something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868313/2720343

Comment: FML...Thanks folks. Figured I could use Object to keep it available for stirng/int/bool. Doesn't seem that is an easy option though. Changing to string works.

Comment: You could also send JSON from the body. It works with the objects too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `public Dictionary<string, string>` Refs in view model in controller and map to `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form-data as to be cast by the framework into a NewMeta object.

That mean the structure of your data has to be exactly the same than what your controller expected.
So you need only 2 keys : Refs (as a json dictionary) and File.